# Where was the money transferred to in The Night Manager?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-night-manager

In [The Night Manager](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p03g13rt), episode 6:

> Before the weapons are destroyed Jonathan Pine transfers the first payment of 300M out of the tradepass bank account and into another bank account

So, where (or to whom) did he transfer the money?

Answer (score 3):

That was a great series. Where the money went? Well he was a British Operative  and they (British Intelligence) wouldn't just let Pine keep the money so one can assume it went to  British Intelligence one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding was that he transferred the money to his own account. He was working for the government, but not as a fully employed agent. He was an asset. I expect that the money wasn't important in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the book, but in the series, I don't think there's any understanding on the part of the UK/US government how the shake-down happened at all.  Pine let them know about the arms shipments, and subsequently had them blown up, but I'm not sure he ever mentioned how the money would actually change hands for the shipments.  Indeed, the issue of whether he was even still working for the UK/US was raised repeatedly, and it was sort of accepted that he had turned.  No details of what he was doing was ever really discussed.

The 300 mil, how it was authenticated, who owned it, where it went, etc, was never known by the UK/US agents, so I'm assuming the money went to Pine.